# Search Through List Array

Tags: c#, list

I have a array of lists lists[k] (multiple lists).

I want to search if a variable PointF from a list[k] is equals to any of the elements of the lists EXCEPT the list where that variable PointF comes from.

Something like search on lists k+1,k+2,k+n and k-1,k-2,k-n except k.

```
for (int k = 0; k < drone.Length; k++) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) 
        {
            list[k].Add(new PointF(i,j));
        }
    }

    // now I want to search if a variable PointF 
    // from a list[k] is equals to any of the elements 
    // of the lists except the list where that variable PointF comes from
}
```

Comment: Do you want to search for a specific given point or do you want to determine if there is any point in any list that also exists in another list?

Comment: I take an element from the list and I want to compare that element with all elements of all lists except the list where that element came from.

Comment: Ok, so you know `k`? And is this a typo and `drone` is `list` or is there some other magic in `drone`?

Comment: I guess the `j <= (10; j++)` is a typo, isn´t it?

Comment: yes. sorry. forgot to remove.

Comment: Of which type *is* `list[k]`?

Comment: drone.length is an integer. I use it to create a list for each drone.

Comment: PointF. Basically I create a list of points for each drone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know `k` (the index of the list where your point came from) you can do this with this little linq implementation:

```
private bool PointExistsInAnotherList(List<PointF>[] lists, int k, PointF p)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, lists.Length)
                     .Where(i => i != k)
                     .Any(i => lists[i].Any(point => point.Equals(p)));

}
```

This checks for all lists except `lists[k]` if any of the points in that list equals the given point `p`. If one matching point is found, it returns `true` immediatly.

---

If you want to know the index of the list that contains the matching point, you can do this:

```
private int PointExistsInAnotherList(List<PointF>[] lists, int k, PointF p)
{
    for (int i=0; i<lists.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == k) continue;
        if (lists[i].Any(point => point.Equals(p)) return i;                                  
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This returns the index (`i`) of the first list that contains a point equal to `p`, or `-1` if no matching point was found.

Comment: Are you there??

Comment: Do you know how instead of returning a bool. I wanted to return which k list it was found?

Comment: @TiagoSilva Update my answer.

Comment: i cant manage to make it work with my code. Can you check it please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091176/c-sharp-searching-on-lists