# C# - Searching for a Point on Lists

Tags: c#, list

I'm creating a List of points for each quadcopter to create a safe area around it and avoid other quadcopters to go near each other.

My code already creates a list of points to create a safe area around it (since distance is going from -20 to +20 it creates 1600 points (40*40)).

**Now I want to compare if the drone[k].posicao_atual (actual position) is inside the safe area of other drones. If it does I just want a debug message for now.**

I asked for a code to s*earch every other list except the list created by the drone itself* **(the last If statement and it never goes true. Even when the drone is inside the safe area it never enters the if statement)**.

Any help?

```
 PointF posicao_desejada = new Point(0, 0);
    PointF posicao_atual = new Point(0, 0);    
    List<PointF>[] lista_colisoes;
    int distancia = 20;

      for (int i = 0; i < drone.Length; i++)
        {

            lista_colisoes[i] = new List<PointF>();
          }



   for (int k = 0; k < drone.Length; k++)
        {

            lista_colisoes[k].Clear();

            for (int i = (int)posicao_atual.X - distancia; i <= (int)posicao_atual.X + distancia; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = (int)posicao_atual.Y - distancia; j <= (int)posicao_atual.Y + distancia; j++)
                    {
                        lista_colisoes[k].Add(new PointF(i, j));
                    }

                }

                if (Enumerable.Range(0, drone.Length).Where(i => i != k).
                  Any(list => lista_colisoes.Any(ponto => ponto.Equals(drone[k].posicao_atual))))
                {
                   Debug.WriteLine("Entered Safe Area")
                   //never enters here
                }

            }
```

The Green drone is inside the Red's drone safe area and it doesnt enter the if statement.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YAcb.png)

Comment: @René Vogt can you please help me? :/

Comment: I have to apologize, there was a mistake in my answer to your previous question: the part in the outer `Any(...)` is wrong. The lambda still takes an `int` as argument and you need to check `Any(i => lista_colisoes[i].Any(ponto => ...))`. Updated my previous answer.